# symfony many-to-many relation loops properties instead of objects

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a many-to-many relation with a linked table. See (simplified) schema below.
Created according to the tutorial (http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/05-Data-Fixtures#chapter_05_many_to_many)

The schema imports/builds correct and phpmyadmin shows the foreign keys correct.
I'm under the impression that afterwards in the 'locatie' module's indexSuccess template i can call:

```
foreach($locatie->getProducts() as $oProduct):
    echo $oProduct->naam;
endforeach;
```

But that doesnt work, because $oProduct doesnt appear to be an object but a string representing each property in the product class. The foreach simply loops the properties of the first product instead of the product list.
Anybody any advice?

---

Schema

```
Locatie:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: locatie
    columns:
      locatie_id:
        type: integer(4)
        fixed: false
        unsigned: true
        primary: true
        autoincrement: true
      naam:
        type: string(255)
        fixed: false
        unsigned: false
        primary: false
        notnull: true
        autoincrement: false
LocatieProduct:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: locatie_product
  columns:
    locatie_product_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    locatie_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    product_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Locatie:
      local: locatie_id
      foreign: locatie_id
      foreignAlias: LocatieProducts
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Product:
      local: product_id
      foreign: product_id
      foreignAlias: LocatieProducts
      onDelete: CASCADE
Product:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: product
  columns:
    product_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    naam:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have Products defined as a relation on Locatie. Change your schema to:

```
Locatie:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: locatie #this isn't necssary, by the way
  columns:
    #etc
  relations:
    Products:
      class: Product
      type: many
      refClass: LocatieProduct
      local: locatie_id #the field on LocatieProduct that is an FK to the id of the current table (Locatie)
      foreign: product_id #the field on LocatieProduct that is an FK to the id of the class (Product)
```

Also note that you do not need the field locatie_product_id on LocatieProduct. If you do want that table to have a single primary key, I would simply name it id.

[Here's more from the Doctrine book](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en#relationships%3amany-to-many).

Comment: This solves the problem, i missed the many and refClass. I'm new to this whole doctrine stuff but my thinking was right, that i should be able to retrieve products directly from my locatie model. Thanks Jeremy!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, tomvo.

The ORM creates a model for your intermediate or "through" class, so you have an extra class named **LocatieProduct** you're not expecting.  You would use it like this:

```
foreach($locatie->getLocatieProducts()->getProduct() as $oProduct):
    echo $oProduct->naam;
endforeach;
```

The best way for learning how to access the related objects is to read the generated code in `lib/model/doctrine/base/`.

I often add additional methods to the model for convenience.  For example, in `lib/model/doctrine/Locatie.class.php` you can add a function to work more like you expect:

```
public function getProducts() {
    $a = array();
    foreach ($this->getLocatieProducts()->getProduct() as $p) {
        $a[] = $p;
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Nathan, your solution works too but I find the one where you call getProducts() directly from Locatie (using refClass) easier. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Symfony scape strategy wraps objets when rendering, you should try to get the raw value in order to do what you want. Here is an exmaple:

```
foreach($locatie->getRawValue()->getProducts() as $oProduct):
    echo sfOutputEscaper::unescape($oProduct->naam);
endforeach;
```

Hope that helps solve your problem!

Comment: This is absolutely not necessary here.